# Configuring Postgres free space per page

Tags: postgresql, storage, fillfactor

We have a update-heavy table experiencing a lot of bloat (10x). I want to increase the free-space left unused in each page, to make it more likely that updates write the new MVCC tuple on the same page (helping us take advantage of "Heap Only Tuples" more effectively).

I'm pretty sure I've seen a way to configure the "free space left per page" on a per table basis at some point, but for the life of me I can't find it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching [`fillfactor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS).

```
-- set 80% for new data
postgres=# ALTER TABLE boo SET (fillfactor = 80);
ALTER TABLE
```